# How Can I Render Xetex Using Swift

Tags: swift, bash, cocoa, latex, xetex

I am working on a Cocoa application using Swift 4.0 and I am trying to render LaTeX using a xetex compiler. The main draw of my application is that it's supposed to be able to render using different .ttf's so that's why I believe I need xetex (or even luaLaTeX).

## Here's what I tried

1. I considered using a cloud-based LaTeX renderer so I wouldn't have to worry about installing Xetex for each system but this didn't pan out very well because I could only find a paid service that does this in Node.js which I don't think I can use.
2. Next, I assumed that the user had followed an instruction to download xetex online and I used a system call via Process() using the /Library/TeX/texbin/xetex command and this almost worked but Xcode grumbled about security giving me the message

`compileLatex.sh: line 3: /Library/TeX/texbin/xetex: Operation not permitted`

Are there any known workarounds for this that I can do? If I could somehow bundle in a xetex compiler with my application, I think that would be good but I have no idea how to do something like that.

## Relevent Code

Contents of compileLatex.sh which is called by the Process()

```
#!/bin/bash

/Library/TeX/texbin/xetex "$1"
open "$2"
```

Contents of the ViewController that calls the bash script.

```
let file = "TemplateMODIFIED.tex"

    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

        var env = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
        var path = env["PATH"] as! String
        path = "/Library/TeX/texbin:" + path
        env["PATH"] = path

        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
        task.environment = env
        task.arguments = [dir.path + "/compileLatex.sh", dir.path + "/TemplateMODIFIED.tex", dir.path + "/TemplateMODIFIED.pdf"]
        task.launch()

    }
```

Any advice on either a workaround or best practice I should use is appreciated. Thank you!

UPDATE: I just learned about the project.entitlements file for the Cocoa project so by switching Sandbox mode to off I was able to perform the system call and overcome the `Operation not permitted` error. So I'm able to get it to work, but I'm still not fully satisfied with this solution since the user must download and install xetex before using this application.

Comment: You could write your own “cloud” renderer, basically a call to XeTeX installed on a server you control. Watch out for security concerns (malicious `.tex` files).

Comment: That is actually a really good idea. Thank you!